# Configuration design pattern across Java system

Tags: java, design-patterns, configuration

The question is old hat - what is a proper design to support a configuration file or system configurations across our system?  I've identified the following requirements:

- Should be able to reload live and have changes picked up instantly with no redeploying
- For software applications that rely on the same, e.g., SQL or memcached credentials, should be possible to introduce the change in an isolated place and deploy in one swoop, even if applications are on separate machines in separate locations
- Many processes/machines running the same application supported

And the parts of this design I am struggling with:

- Should each major class take its own "Config" class as an input parameter to the constructor?  Should there be a factory responsible for instantiating with respect to the right config?  Or should each class just read from its own config and reload somewhat automatically?
- If class B derives from class A, or composes around it, would it make sense for the Config file to be inherited?
- Say class A is constructed by M1 and M2 (M for "main") and M1 is responsible for instantiating a resource.  Say the resource relies on MySQL credentials that I expect to be common between M1 and M2, is there a way to avoid the tradeoff of break ownership and put in A's config v. duplicate the resource across M1 and M2's config?

These are the design issues I'm dealing with right now and don't really know the design patterns or frameworks that work here.  I'm in Java so any libraries that solve this are very welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to check out [Apache Commons Config](http://commons.apache.org/configuration), which provides a wide range of features. You can specify multiple configuration sources, and arrange these into a hierarchy. One feature of particular interest is the provision for [Configuration Events](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_events.html#Configuration_Events), allowing your components to register their interest in configuration changes.

The goal of changing config on the fly is seductive, but requires some thought around the design. You need to manage those changes carefully (e.g. what happens if you shrink queue sizes - do you throw away existing elements on the queue ?)

Answer (score 0):

**Should each major class take its own "Config" class as an input parameter to the constructor?**

No, that sounds like an awful design which would unnecessarily overcomplicate a lot of code. I would recommend you to implement a global Configuration class as a singleton. Singleton means that there is only one configuration object, which is a private static variable of your Configuration class and can be acquired with a public static getInstance() method whenever it is needed.

This configuration object should store all configuration parameters as key/value pairs.

Comment: I'd rather inject a class, rather than specify it as a singleton. It'll make testing a *lot* easier

Comment: global across the 4 applications so far and the 20 in-house libraries?